# Segue from Custom Data Cell in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I am new to Swift and IOS, I used to have a normal table view and everything worked.  I have now implemented a Custom Table view cell and was wondering how to implement my PrepareForSegue method with my UITableView.  I want to be able to send the selected Table Cell index to the segue for the next controller to access a certain array position.  Right now the sender Object is a CustomCell: UITableViewCell object.  can I access the table index from that object or some other way?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  OBU Bus Tracker
//
//  Created by AJ Norton on 4/20/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 AJ Norton. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var locations = [String]()
    var overall = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        // check if the user is running the app for the first time
        //        if let firstTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstTime")
        //        {
        //
        //            println("second time")
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            println("worked")
        //            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstTime")
        //        }

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("busSchedule", ofType: "plist")
        {
            if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            {
                locations = dict.keys.array
                overall = dict
            }
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

        return locations.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell: CustomRouteViewCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomRouteViewCell

        cell.locationTitle.text = "\(locations[indexPath.row])"


        return cell
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        println("I was clicked")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("routeToTime", sender: indexPath.row)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        //TODO
        println("\(sender?.integerValue)")
        if segue.identifier == "routeToTime"
        {
            var ttvc =  segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController
            var s = sender as! CustomRouteViewCell
            println("\(s.in)")
            var place = s.indentationLevel as! Int
            var dicts = overall[locations[place]] as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            var arr = dicts["Weekday"] as! [Int]

            ttvc.days = dicts
            ttvc.times = arr.reverse()
        }
    }






}
```

Comment: Is your segue made from the cell or the controller? It sounds like it's from the cell if the sender is the cell, but in that case, you shouldn't be calling performSegue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath (in fact you don't need to implement that method at all).

Comment: That is unknown I am unaware of where the segue is being made.  It no longer is called in my prepareForSegue method.  I am unaware of where the segue is being called.

Comment: Didn't you make the segue? Did you drag from the cell or from the controller icon when you made it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("routeToTime", sender: indexPath.row)
```

you call above method. so in this method:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

the local argument sender is indexPath.row, is NOT a instance of CustomRouteViewCell.

So you can write code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "routeToTime"
    {
        var ttvc =  segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController
        var place = sender as! Int
        var dicts = overall[locations[place]] as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        var arr = dicts["Weekday"] as! [Int]

        ttvc.days = dicts
        ttvc.times = arr.reverse()
    }
}
```

It is best to write code in the MVC patten, so don't store your data in a tableview cell.

Whateve you want do that, you must set a cell's property（For example: rowIndex: Int） that indicate the indexRow of the data in this method 'func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)'. Your code looks like:

```
if segue.identifier == "routeToTime"
    {
        var ttvc =  segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController
        var cell = sender as! CustomRouteViewCell
        var place = cell.indexRow
        var dicts = overall[locations[place]] as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        var arr = dicts["Weekday"] as! [Int]

        ttvc.days = dicts
        ttvc.times = arr.reverse()
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell: CustomRouteViewCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomRouteViewCell

    cell.locationTitle.text = "\(locations[indexPath.row])"
    cell.indexRow = ... //Set the index of cell's data.

    return cell
}
```

By the way, the indentationLevel property is:

> var indentationLevel: Int // adjust content indent. default is 0

Answer (score -1):

How about storing the cell index as a NSUserDefault and retrieving it from the other side?

That way you can use a generic segue created through the storyboard, implement the table cells on selected function.

Comment: There is no such thing as an NSdefault. If you mean NSUserDefaults, that's a bad idea; that's not what they're for. The OP should learn how to properly pass the data in prepareForSegue, not use NSUserDefaults as a crutch.